# Sql command running from SSMS but not from CMD

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

i'm sorry, i am new to programming , i tried to find an answer to my problem but did not find one.
The situation is like this:
I have a barcode scanner that i want to use. This barcode scanner scans the barcode in memory and generates a txt file with date, time and code. The format of the date is dd/mm/yyyy. I want to upload this readings to a SQLExpress database, but the date field is formated -as i understood by default to yyyy-mm-dd
I have a .bat file that calls for a SQL command like this:
the bat file:

sqlcmd -S MYPC\SQLEXPRESS -U test -P test -i "d:\newfolder\update.sql" -o "d:\newfolder\log_%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.txt"

the update.sql file:

INSERT INTO logistica.dbo.test ([data],[ora],[part])
SELECT convert(date,[data],110),[ora],[part]  FROM  openrowset(bulk 'd:\input\BARCODES.txt',FORMATFILE='D:\newfolder\format_file.xml') as t;

The problem is that the sql command above will work from SSMS, but not from cmd.
I get the following error:

Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Server MYPC\SQLEXPRESS, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 1 (data)

Does anyone have a better idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Until i find a solution, i skipped uploading the date field to database and set in database to auto fill with current date the date column.

Comment: give a snippet of what your data looks like